# Скрыть блок-попап в самом теле сайта

Tags: popup

Доброго дня!
Возник такой вопрос - сверстал блок попапа, всё работает, но как сделать, чтобы он не отображался в теле самого сайта отдельным блоком (секцией)?

Comment: По умолчанию прописать стиль display:none; И менять на display:block при вызове popup?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - собирайте его при помощи js или подгружайте с отдельной страницы.

Сборка через js сложнее. Надо создавать элементы через `document.createElement`, потом задавать им свойства... По итогу добавлять в конец body через `document.body.append( my_element );`

Вариант с загрузкой (с использованием jQuery):

```
$('body').append('<div class="popup_loadbox"></div>');
$('.popup_loadbox').load('popup.html');
```